# Nopcommerce inherit code from de nop core controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I'm trying to develop a plugin in `nopcommerce`. To do this I want to replace some of the core code out of `nopcommerce`.

I tried to inherit it via:

```
public class TryingNewProjectController : BasePluginController, Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController
{
   ///// CODE /////  
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'Controllers' does not exist in the namespace 'Nop.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Controllers' does not exist in the namespace 'Nop.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)


I know that this means that im missing a reference but normally i inherit a controller via it's name/location

Comment: Likely it means you are actually missing a reference to be able to use Nop.Web.Controllers

Comment: Thanks for ur opinion. I shall try it.

Comment: It was Web.Controllers.CatalogController

Comment: I edited your question and added an answer so the next person with this question can more easily find their answer.  Feel free to upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It really does mean you are actually missing a reference to be able to use Nop.Web.Controllers.

And as you found out it was Web.Controllers.CatalogController.

So Nop.Web.Controllers was itself expecting the reference.