# Nopcommerce Rewriting Route to overrule core catalog controller via CustomView Engine and Routeprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, route-provider

In my ealier question I asked how to inherit code from the Nop core controller CatalogController. See for the post the Question [Nopcommerce inherit code from de nop core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462771/nopcommerce-inherit-code-from-de-nop-core-controller)

Now i have inherited the code of this core controller but now i want to let nopcommerce use my CatalogController insted of the core controller. To do this i've made use of a CustomViewEnige and a route provider.

After adding the new route:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController",
                  "{category}",
                  new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category" },
                  new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.TryingNewProjectController.Controllers" });
```

I've have changed my Route provider code, So Nopcommerce now sees the route that i want but now i still get the error:

> The current request for action 'Category' on controller type
>   'CatalogController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Category() on type
>   Nop.Plugin.Widgets.TryingNewProjectController.Controllers.CatalogController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Category() on type
>   Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Category(Int32, Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CatalogPagingFilteringModel) on
>   type Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself :) But for other starting nopcommerce developers / starting ASP.Net devlopers, here is the answer:

When u make a new route to a controller / action, then you have to have a unique name for this controller / action in your new plugin. It's sounds very simple but it took me a long time to figure it out...

So here is my old code, that didn't work.....

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController",
                  "{category}",
                  new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category" },
                  new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.TryingNewProjectController.Controllers" });
```

This code works:

```
routes.MapRoute("Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController.Category",
                "{category}",
               new { controller = "TryingNewProject", action = "Category" },
               new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.TryingNewProjectController.Controllers.CatalogController" });
```